JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED') with com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client, version 9.4.1.0
Some legacy code is running on a mainframe that uses JMS classes to connect to MQ.
The older version uses Java 8, Java EE with Spring 5 and IBM-provided JARs: com.ibm.mq.jar, com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar, com.ibm.mqjms.jar.
After we switched to Java 17, Jakarta EE and Spring 6 the code started failing with the error:
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'XXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYY'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:222)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:156)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1172)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:128)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.<init>(WMQMessageConsumer.java:486)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createConsumer(WMQSession.java:934)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createConsumer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1012)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createConsumer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1097)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsQueueSessionImpl.createReceiver(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:103)
    at com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueSession.createReceiver(MQQueueSession.java:87)
    at xxxx.api.messaging.JMSMessagingManager.open(JMSMessagingManager.java:279)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)


The new code uses dependency: implementation group: 'com.ibm.mq', name: 'com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client', version: '9.4.1.0'
as mentioned above we need to use Jakarta EE instead of Java EE, as Spring 6 supports Jakarta EE 9.
The setup that fails, we use to run the application locally on a Windows machine while connecting to remote queues in client mode.
Application in production located on the same host as MQ and uses binding mode (no password, only user ID which is MVS user ID)
We use SecExit to connect in client mode with login and password (again, this is only for the development environment on local machines):
mq.security.exit        = biz.capitalware.mqausx.MQAUSXJ2EE

If I intentionally use the wrong user ID or password I get a different error:
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'xxxxxxx(1415)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2009],3=xxxxxxxxx(1415),4=,5=RemoteConnection.asyncConnectionBroken]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13703)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.access$100(RemoteFAP.java:13206)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1456)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1397)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:417)


So, I assume authentication passes OK, but then when Queue listener created something goes wrong.
I have searched for this problem and read these discussions:
IBM MQ JMS not working after migration to Spring Boot 3 with com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client.jar 9.3
and this
IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')
I have tried different combinations of
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=true -Duser.name=xxxxx
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=false -Duser.name=xxxxx
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.jmqi.useMQCSPauthentication=false
Nothing helped. In fact no difference, the only difference I see when I try the wrong password.
Since the code works with Java 8 and MQ JMS libs for Java EE, I do not want to modify any setting on QMGR side, mostly because this new set up only needed for development environment.
Any help / hint is appreciated.

Have you tried checking the mainframe security exit logs or opening a case with the security exit vendor?

Hi @JoshMc, I haven't checked the logs yet. The problem is that it's not that simple. It's a legacy application, and we have no dedicated admin. I am really not sure what to ask, as my expertise is in another area. Another reason that stops me -- with Java 8 and older MQ JMS libs code works fine, so I suspect I will get an answer that the server side is properly configured. My idea is that maybe I need to put some extra properties in the MQ queue connection factory, or something like that. Thank you for your suggestions.

What version of MQ are the old jar files from?   You can check the MANIFEST.MF file.

The MQ libs which work on Windows are:
Specification-Version: 9.1.0.4
Implementation-Version: 9.1.0.4 - V910-PH18782-L191204
The SecExit lib on client side MQAUSXJ.jar is very dated:
Manifest-Version: 1.3.0
Created-By: Roger Lacroix, Capitalware Inc.
The timestamp inside JAR is 2008

Do you connect to the same channel with old and new jars?   Do you run as the same user?

The logs don't suggest it, but as you will have updated your JRE/JDK, do you have TLS enabled? if so what are you setting for ibm.mq.sslCipherSuite and ibm.mq.sslCipherSpec in the application.properties ? What do you get for java -version ?

@JoshMc Yes, I use basically the same code, just with different JREs (8 and 17). The property file with MQ connection attributes is the same (so, the same MQ channel). The only difference is that Java EE classes for JMS were replaced with Jakarta EE classes (imports, etc.).

@chughts
I use Java 17 : openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18                                                                                                                                                                                OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8)
as for ibm.mq.sslCipherSuite and ibm.mq.sslCipherSpec I did not do anything --never set it up.

Is the Java 8, a Temurin distribution also? So the queue manager doesn't have TLS set up?

Java 8 is pre-bundled with WAS 9, from IBM (did not try other JREs):
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.5.20 - pwa6480sr5fp20-20180802_01(SR5 FP20))                                                                                                                            IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20180731_393394 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)

@chughts QMGR has no TLS-related settings on the client side

I guess if you are normally running on bindings mode, then there isn't TLS enabled on the server side neither.

Guys, this is not a Java or JVM issue. @BaratSahdzijeu , please contact Capitalware Support. I'm 99% sure it is related to the UserId that the MQAUSX server-side component is setting for the connection. Barat can you send a copy of the MQAUSX server-side log file to Capitalware Support? MQAUSX has many configuration options on what your UserId the connection will use. i.e. Authenticated UserId, RemoteUserId, MCAUSER, etc... The RC of 2035 is coming from the queue manager because whatever the UserId that is set for the connection does not have permission.

Are you passing a username and/or password to the createQueueConnection call?

Yes, of course: queueConn = queueConnFactory.createQueueConnection(mqUsername, mqPassword);
As described here: https://www.capitalware.com/dl/docs/MQAUSX_Programming_Guide.pdf

I would strongly suggest you contact Capitalware Support.
It appears you have configured & are using the client-side security exit for MQ Authenticate User Security Exit (MQAUSX) and I presume that the z/OS MQAUSX server-side security exit is fully configured.

Application in production located on the same host as MQ and uses binding mode (no password, only user ID which is MVS user ID)

That comment does not make any sense. So, you are running the Java application on z/OS in the same LPAR as the z/OS queue manager? Also, in Bindings mode, the MQ client library does not use a channel, hence, a channel security exit would not be invoked.

If I intentionally use the wrong user ID or password I get a different error:
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9204

The reason code of 2009 means that the MQAUSX server-side security exit shutdown the channel. i.e. Failed authenication.
You said that you switched from using MQ v8.0 to the latest MQ CSD 9.4.1.0 but IBM has made changes to the underlining handling of UserId sent between the client-side to the server-side queue manager. I'm willing to bet you are getting burnt by this.

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').

It appears that your application's UserId & Password were successfully authenticated by the MQAUSX server-side security exit but failed on RACF/ACF2 authorization for "connecting to the queue manager" or "opening a queue" because the UserId being used for authorization is mismatched.
Ask your z/OS MQAdmin to check the MQAUSX log file to see what MQAUSX outputted It will have a detailed output for the authenticated UserId and the UserId used for accessing the z/OS queue manager. Also, ask the z/OS MQAdmin if the queue manager's log file recorded the RC of 2035 & what was in the error message.
Finally, did you switch channel names to connect to the z/OS queue manager? If so, what value is in the MCAUSER field of the old channel and new channel?

Thank you @Roger for the reply. Regarding "That comment does not make any sense. "
Yes, we are running the application in DEV/FT/PROD on the same LPAR as QMGR; hence, we don't use SecExit and password. Only the MVS user ID that runs the application is checked during QMGR authorization. The problem I have and asking in this SO question is only about configuring the local development environment on a Windows machine.

@BaratSahdzijeu , please contact Capitalware Support. I'm 99% sure it is related to the UserId that the MQAUSX server-side component is setting for the connection. Barat can you send a copy of the MQAUSX server-side log file to Capitalware Support? MQAUSX has many configuration options on what your UserId the connection will use. i.e. Authenticated UserId, RemoteUserId, MCAUSER, etc... The RC of 2035 is coming from the queue manager because whatever the UserId that is set for the connection does not have permission.
